# MAX Partitioning in ETL using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, partition-by

I have a query in SQL Server where I am using `MAX OVER Partition BY`.

```
MAX(Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY [Variable8] 
                    ORDER BY [RouterCallKeySequenceNumber] ASC) AS MaxDuration
```

I would like to implement this in ETL using SSIS.

To implement, I have tried to implement similar to how we can implement Row Number.

I have added a SORT transformation and sorted by Variable8 and RouterCallKeySequenceNumber and then I have added a Script transformation.

```
    string _variable8 = "";
    int _max_duration;

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        _max_duration = Row.Duration;

        if (Row.Variable8 != _variable8)
        {
            _max_duration = Row.Duration;
            Row.maxduration = _max_duration;

            _variable8 = Row.Variable8;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Row.Duration >= _max_duration)
            {
                Row.maxduration = _max_duration;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the data that I have -

```
Variable8   RouterCallKeySequenceNumber Duration
153084-2490 0                           265     
153084-2490 1                           161     
153084-2490 2                           197
```

The solution that I need is as below -

```
Variable8   RouterCallKeySequenceNumber Duration    Max Duration
153084-2490 0                           265         265
153084-2490 1                           161         265
153084-2490 2                           197         265
```

But this does not return the desired value.

I would appreciate if you can provide any help.

Thanks

Comment: `But this does not return the desired value.` What is your desired result? What is the current result? Can you give us some sample data and describe what you're trying to do here?

Comment: What I need is to show is max value on each duplicate row.